# Attempt to use QCircuit nghost and \vdots

Tags: math-mode, qcircuit

I am working on a project that takes advantage of the QCircuit library. I have to say that I have run into a lot of problems with this library that has poor documentation as to what can be done. However, in compiling this circuit, two problems emerge that I report here directly from Overleaf. The code compiles, the result is what I wanted to get however I don't understand what the error is due to, because it comes from this block. Did I get something wrong in the notation? I don't know what else to find ...

I get **Missing $ inserted** at the line before the first `\raisebox{-2.3em}{=}` and at the line before `\end{center}`

Any suggestions? I was supposing that was a problem of **nghost** or **vdots**, but I'm not sure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

% General Settings
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{mathtools}


% Quantum circuit package
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \mbox{
            \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
                & \qw                         & \multigate{2}{G} & \qw                     & \qw \\
                & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots}     & \nghost{G}       & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots} &     \\
                & \qw                         & \ghost{G}        & \qw                     & \qw
            }
        }
        \raisebox{-2.3em}{=}
        \mbox{
            \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
                & \qw
                & \multigate{2}{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \qw
                & \multigate{2}{
                    \begin{array}{ll}
                        \ket{0}^{\otimes n} \rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n} \\
                        \ket{x}^{\otimes n} \rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
                    \end{array}}
                & \qw
                & \multigate{2}{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \qw
                & \qw 
                \\
                & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots}
                & \nghost{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots}
                & \nghost{
                    \begin{array}{cc}
                        \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\\
                        \ket{x}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
                    \end{array}}
                & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots}
                & \nghost{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots}
                &
                \\
                & \qw
                & \ghost{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \qw
                & \ghost{
                    \begin{array}{ll}
                        \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\\
                        \ket{x}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
                    \end{array}}
                & \qw
                & \ghost{H^{\otimes n}}
                & \qw
                & \qw
            }
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please, provide a minimal, yet complete, compilable code to allow people to reproduce your issue.

Comment: In addition, using your code in the `standalone` class with only `qcircuit` and `braket` loaded as packages, the code compiles correctly.

Comment: I update the code, yes, I agree with the fact that compiling only with the two packages that you mention it goes well, but I don't understand what is wrong with other packages...

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error with the updated code. Simply surrounding `\vdots` by `$` in the `raisebox` argument did the trick for me. In addition, you might want to surround the `=` symbol in the solitary `raisebox` by `$` to have the math mode equal symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the kernel, `\vdots` is defined as a command that can be used both in text and math, but `mathdots` redefines it to be only usable in math mode.

Solution: wrap it inside `$...$`.

Even better, do

```
\newcommand{\qvdots}{% \vdots for qcircuit
  \raisebox{0.3em}{\ensuremath{\vdots}}%
}
```

and use `\qvdots`.

There are also some spurious spaces that make it difficult to control the horizontal spacing. Check the `<---` marks I added to the code.

The `hyperref` package should be loaded last (only some packages need to go behind it, none that you're loading).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

% General Settings
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{mathtools}


% Quantum circuit package
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=blue,
}
\urlstyle{same}

\newcommand{\qvdots}{% \vdots for qcircuit
  \raisebox{0.3em}{\ensuremath{\vdots}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \mbox{% <---
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
      & \qw     & \multigate{2}{G} & \qw     & \qw \\
      & \qvdots & \nghost{G}       & \qvdots &     \\
      & \qw     & \ghost{G}        & \qw     & \qw
    }% <---
  }% <---
  \quad\raisebox{-2.3em}{=}\quad % <---
  \mbox{% <---
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
      & \qw
      & \multigate{2}{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qw
      & \multigate{2}{
          \begin{array}{ll}
          \ket{0}^{\otimes n} \rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n} \\
          \ket{x}^{\otimes n} \rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
          \end{array}
        }
      & \qw
      & \multigate{2}{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qw
      & \qw 
      \\
      & \qvdots
      & \nghost{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qvdots
      & \nghost{
          \begin{array}{cc}
            \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\\
            \ket{x}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
          \end{array}
        }
      & \qvdots
      & \nghost{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qvdots
      &
      \\
      & \qw
      & \ghost{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qw
      & \ghost{
          \begin{array}{ll}
            \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow \ket{0}^{\otimes n}\\
            \ket{x}^{\otimes n}\rightarrow -\ket{x}^{\otimes n}
          \end{array}
        }
      & \qw
      & \ghost{H^{\otimes n}}
      & \qw
      & \qw
    }% <---
  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]